# How to make an interactive element disappear for screenreaders, but where the content still is readable by screenreaders

Tags: html, button, accessibility, tabindex, nvda

I use a table to display content, where each row (each cell in the row) should be clickable by mouse users. But where keyboard users just should be able to click a single button in that row (to save them from a lot of clicks) - se picture below:
[image]

Here is the true challenge: the td's with click-events / buttons in them should at the same time not be visible for screenreaders as interactive elements in their "elements list" (as it is called in NVDA), but the content should still be reachable for them as normal reading content - see picture below:
[image]

I added tabindex="-1" to the interactive elements, where keyboard users now not will be able to reach the td's (as I intended), but they will still be reachable by screenviewers.

When I then add aria-hidden="true" to these elements, the elements will not be reachable by screenreaders at all (which I not intended).

The element's content should still be reachable as normal reading text for screenviewers - it's just the interactive part which should not be reachable.

Any ideas?  - See simplified code example below:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                Rooms
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Area
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Rent
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Deposit
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Info
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                Quantity
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="result-rooms" rowspan="2">
                <span><span>1</span></span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-sqm" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>39</span> m<sup>2</sup></span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-rent" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>2218</span> DKK/month</span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-deposit" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>8208</span> DKK</span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-info" rowspan="2">
                <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" title="Info">
                    <span class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
            <td class="result-add ng-scope" rowspan="2">
                <div class="add-to-basket ng-isolate-scope">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-heart ng-scope btn-primary btn-icon-light" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleWish(tenG.tenancies[$index], ten.Rooms, $index)" aria-label="Add 2 to basket">
                        <span>Add 2</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="result-sqm" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>40</span> m<sup>2</sup></span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-rent" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>2251</span> DKK/month</span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-deposit" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                <span><span>8640</span> DKK</span>
            </td>
            <td class="result-info" rowspan="2">
                <button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.viewTenancy(ten)" title="Info">
                    <span class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please post a small but concrete example with some code to help understanding the issue ? At the moment without any example, it's hard to understand what is really wanted / what the user should be able to do with the interface at the end, and hence, it's hard to help you. Depending on what is wanted, maybe there is a much better solution than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will look into it and update this question with a code example and maybe a mockup of the interface as soon as I can.

Comment: Updated with screenshots and simplified code example - I hope it helps to understand my challenge.

Comment: Remove all aria-hidden=true, they destroy accessibility for nothing. Remove all tabindex=-1 as well, they are useless since `<td>` aren't focusable by default. IN your example, only buttons in the info column are reachable for keyboard users. Isn't that you wanted? I still  don't understand well what's your problem.